# Codeigniter 4 - call method from another controller

Tags: codeigniter-4

How to call "functionA" from "ClassA" in "functionB" inside "ClassB" ?

```php
class Base extends BaseController
{
    public function header()
    {
        echo view('common/header');
        echo view('common/header-nav');
    }
}

class Example extends BaseController
{
    public function myfunction()
        // how to call function header from base class
        return view('internet/swiatlowod');
    }   
}
```

Comment: What are the namespaces of each Class? Without those I'd be guessing which is why we namespaces removes any confusion.

Comment: Namespace: "namespace App\Controllers;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there are many ways to do this...

One such way, might be like...

1. Assume that example.php is the required Frontend so we will need a route to it.

In app\Config\Routes.php we need the entry

```
$routes->get('/example', 'Example::index');
```

**This lets us use the URL your-site dot com/example**

Now we need to decide how we want to use the functions in Base inside Example. So we could do the following...

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

class Example extends BaseController {

    protected $base;

    /**
    * This is the main entry point for this example.
    */
    public function index() {
        $this->base = new Base(); // Create an instance
        $this->myfunction();
    }


    public function myfunction() {
        echo $this->base->header();       // Output from header
        echo view('internet/swiatlowod'); // Output from local view
    }
}
```

When and where you use new Base() is up to you, but you need to use before you need it (obviously).

You could do it in a constructor, you could do it in a parent class and extend it so it is common to a group of controllers.

It's up to you.